# C Variable Assignement Analysis using Python and Clang

Tags: python, clang

I would like to use the Clang library to parse a C source file and find all read and write variable accesses in a specific function declaration, that is all variable assignments. Somehow the code below misses any variable asignment in a function declaration. That is, no node was found for the assignment in the for loop as well as the variable assignment before the loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
import clang.cindex                        # Python bindings for libclang (LLVM)

def findVariableAccessesInFunc(cFileName, functionName):
    """
    Find all read and write variable accesses in a specific function.

    Args:
        cFileName (str): Path to the C source file.
        functionName (str): Name of the function to analyze.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    # Create an index
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

    # Parse the translation unit
    translationUnit = index.parse(cFileName)

    # Initialize a flag to track if we're inside the target function
    insideTargetFunction = False

    # Traverse through the nodes in the translation unit
    for node in translationUnit.cursor.walk_preorder():

        LOGGER.info("Node Info:")
        LOGGER.info(f"    Kind: {node.kind}")
        LOGGER.info(f"    Spelling: {node.spelling}")
        LOGGER.info(f"    Access Specifier: {node.access_specifier}")

        # Check if the current node represents a function definition
        # and NOT a function declaration only
        if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL and node.is_definition():

            # Check if the current function is the target function
            insideTargetFunction = (node.spelling == functionName)

            # Check if the node's name is in the list of functions to analyze
            if insideTargetFunction:

                # Check if a child node is a variable declaration
                if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.VAR_DECL:
                    # Found a variable declaration - print its name and access specifier
                    LOGGER.info(f"Variable: {node.spelling}, Access Type: {node.access_specifier}")


                # Check if a child node in the Clang AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) represents a binary operator
                if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.BINARY_OPERATOR:
                    if node.operator == '=':
                        # Found a write access
                        LOGGER.info(f"Write access to: {node.operand.spelling}")

                # Check if a child node is a reference to a variable
                elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.DECL_REF_EXPR:
                    # Found a read access - print the variable being read
                    LOGGER.info(f"Read access to: {node.spelling}")
```

Not preprocessed C source code that does NOT work, i.e. assignments are not recognized as nodes:

```
#ifndef CPU_SET_SEQUENCE_POINT
#define CPU_SET_SEQUENCE_POINT() asm volatile ("" ::: "memory")
#endif

void function(void);

bool CoEng_bObdTmrInctg;    
      
#pragma section ".sbss" awBs
sint16 Epm_nEng;
#pragma section
    
#pragma section ".bss.sysram_dai_swc_data.a2" awB
extern uint8 variable_A;
uint8 variable_A__C13_0;
#pragma section

#pragma section ".bss.sysram_dai_swc_data.a2" awB
extern uint8 variable_B;
uint8 variable_B__C13_0;
#pragma section

#pragma section ".bss.sysram_dai_swc_data.a2" awB
extern uint16 variable_Array[];
uint16 variable_Array__C13_0[24];
#pragma section
    

void function(void)
{
    CPU_SET_SEQUENCE_POINT();        // Line 30
    variable_A__C13_0 = variable_A;  // Line 31
            
    CPU_SET_SEQUENCE_POINT();        // Line 33
    variable_B__C13_0 = variable_B;  // Line 34

    CPU_SET_SEQUENCE_POINT();        // Line 36
    {
        uint copyctr = 24U;
        uint16 *pSrc = &variable_Array[0];
        uint16 *pDest = &variable_Array__C13_0[0];
        
        GetLock();

        while (copyctr > 0U)
        {
            *pDest = *pSrc;
            pDest++;
            pSrc++;
            copyctr--;
        }

        ReleaseLock();
    }

}
```

As you can see only the macros / assembly instructions in the function body are recognized by clang. See the log file

```
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO: Node Info at line 30:
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Kind: CursorKind.ASM_STMT
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Spelling: 
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Access Specifier: AccessSpecifier.INVALID
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO: Node Info at line 33:
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Kind: CursorKind.ASM_STMT
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Spelling: 
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Access Specifier: AccessSpecifier.INVALID
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO: Node Info at line 36:
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Kind: CursorKind.ASM_STMT
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Spelling: 
2023-11-08 - 15:04:21 - INFO:     Access Specifier: AccessSpecifier.INVALID
```

Lines 31 and 34, where variable assignements take place, are missed by clang. This happens for both preprocessed and not preprocessed file.

```
variable_A__C13_0 = variable_A; // line #31
        
variable_B__C13_0 = variable_B; // line #34
```

Removing assembly statements at line #30 and #33 does not make it better.

Comment: How do you have an assignment in a function declaration? And what does that have to do with a `for` loop? Can you post example source code that it's not parsing correctly?

Comment: Please see my edited post with the source code example.

Comment: When you encounter the head of the function definition, you need to recurse into it. Your code never actually processes the nodes inside the function because the condition `node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL` is not true for the following iterations.

Comment: No, for this code `node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL` is TRUE when head of the function definition is encountered. As you can see from the LOG above, the assembly calls on lines 30, 33 and 36 are processed. These assembly calls are located inside of the function body.

Comment: But it's not true on an assignment statement like #31. Why would you expect it to process those lines?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the clang library to tell how to do it, but you want to set a flag true when you encounter the head of a function definition, and clear it when you reach the end. Then you can check this flag to process the statements within the function.

Comment: The assignment on statatment like #31 might be FALSE, but take a look at my code above - the node info is logged using `LOGGER.info` function, and it is logged before the call to `node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FUNCTION_DECL`. The logging happens always, uncodinationaly so to say. It looks like the clang simply misses these variable assignments.